# Как составить структуру всех таблиц в текущей схеме?

Tags: sql, oracle

Уже выяснил, что для описания таблицы можно использовать таблицу:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','<my table name>','<table owner>') from dual;
```

Также выяснил, что можно получить список таблиц для текущего пользователя, используя запрос:

```
select table_name from user_tables;
```

Однако мне нужно найти способ, совместить эти два способа, чтобы получить (желательно как SQL файл) вывод, который описывает все таблицы в текущей схеме.

Как можно это сделать?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How do I write the table structure in Oracle from an existing schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59199766) от участника [@Prasanna Narayanan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390167/prasanna-narayanan)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/59199766

Answer (score 2):

Вызовите функцию `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` в запросе с таблицей `user_tables`:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl ('TABLE', table_name, user) 
from   user_tables;
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59199957) от участника [@Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)</sub>